# React Native Component Renders under other components inside a modal

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jsx

I have a modal that contains various children components. One of them being a calendar component  that is opened after pressing the text "Select Date"

Upon opening the Calendar component renders underneath the other components on the page.

I have tried using position: 'absolute' with a higher zIndex but I still cannot get the Calendar Component to render on top of everything else...how can I accomplish this?

[image: Here is an image of what is occuring]

[image: This is wrapped in a View component with position: absolute and a high zindex]

[image: This is wrapped in a View component with position: absolute and a high zindex]

JSX For the components

```
<View style={styles.container}>

     <View style={styles.routineitems}>
            <TouchableOpacity >
              <Text style={{ }}>Due Date</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>calendarShouldShow(calendarVisible)}>
               <Text style={{ }}>Select Date</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
     </View>

     <Calendar style={{position: 'absolute',zIndex: 4}}/>

     <View style={styles.routineitems}>
            <Text>Tags</Text>
            <DropDownPicker
              placeholder="Tags"
            />
     </View>

     <View style={styles.routineitems}>
             <Text>Notes</Text>
                    
             <TextInput
                style={styles.input}
                onChangeText ={ value => setNotes(value)}
                value={notes}
                laceholder="Notes"
                textAlign={'right'}
              />
      </View>

</View>
```

STYLESHEET

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
container: {
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'center',
        width: '100%'
    },
routineitems: {
        display: 'flex',
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'space-between',
        width: '90%',
        marginBottom: '1%',
        marginTop: '1%',
        alignItems: 'center',
        zIndex: 0
    },
input: {
        height: 40,
        width: '30%',
        borderRadius: 20,
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        fontSize: 50,
        textAlignVertical:'bottom', 
        paddingTop: 0, 
        paddingBottom:0,
        textAlign: 'right'
    }
});
```

Comment: I would definitely remove the position: absolute, styling, that just a hack and isn't going to be a good solution for you. What happens if you remove that styling, and wrap your calendar in a View tag?

Comment: When I remove the absolute styling it puts the calendar component in line with the others and pushes them down..off of the modal..I am trying to have the effect as in the photo just overlayed ontop of the othe components

Comment: Wrapping it in a View component and giving that view a style of absolute is actually working...I just have to manually position it in the modal at that point

Comment: Well then, sounds like it wouldn't be too bad to do.

Comment: Yes I think that might be the way to go. But this actually places the calendar on top of all of the components accept the ones below it, ones rendered after, if that makes sense so its not totally working

Comment: can you post another picture of what it looks like now?

Comment: Also, a quick sketch, even in something like MS paint of what you WANT it to look like will help if you can.

Comment: 2 Photos added for now I will come up with a sketch as well!

Comment: Ah I see now, its blocking the tags dropdown, and the notes?

Comment: yes I want the tags drop down to have a higher zindex than the notes and be on top of it...it worked for the calendar but not for the drop-down component..